# Homography point estimation looks incorrect

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I'm attempting to map the locations of people's feet to  a top down view of a game area. The top part of the image is the top down view and the bottom half is the camera view. I've used the center net to calculate the homography for the points on each person's feet, however, when they are projected on the top down view, two of the locations look accurate (point 1 & 2) while the other two look off (point 3 & 4). Am I missing something about homography that makes this type of problem not possible?

[image]

```
ground_points_below_net = np.array([
    (971, 824), # Top Middle
    (1057, 835), # Middle Right
    (970, 849), # Bottom Middle
    (882, 837), # Middle Left
])

top_down_net = np.array([
    (941, 215), # Top Middle
    (959, 233), # Middle Right
    (941, 251), # Bottom Middle
    (923, 233), # Middle Left
])

feet_xys = np.array([
    (98, 1026),
    (595, 784),
    (1236, 775),
    (1529, 914),
])

h, status = cv2.findHomography(ground_points_below_net, top_down_net)
for x,y in feet_xys:
    dot = h@np.array([x,y,1]).reshape(3,1)
    pt = tuple((dot * (1/dot[2]))[:2].reshape(2))
    print(pt)
```

```
(885.4008189634716, 176.32433195979408) # Point 1
(981.06494824745, 168.66222074226133) # Point 2
(1221.1758128000006, 516.5530403995187) # Point 3
(3356.1897310438176, -3396.46309797462) # Point 4
```

Comment: It looks like just by adjusting the `ground_points_below_net` by a pixel in either direction makes it look way more believable. Do you think it is just a matter of it being such a small area that any slight change makes a big impact?

Comment: [mre] please. four reference points in each view are required to calculate the homography. -- numerical stability is terrible if you take points that close together for that center "square". it's like balancing a tripod on a postage stamp.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've updated the code snippet to include the four reference points, please let me know if you need additional code.

Comment: as suspected, the homography (given those points) is a train wreck. those points are too close together and too squashed to give decent results. "postage stamp".

Comment: Use a bigger "calibration" region or much higher accuracy in selecting the points in the pixels.